# iOS: check modulus with double value

Tags: ios, double, modulus

This is my code to check the modulus:

```
float module = fmod(self.count_bar, 0.3);
NSLog(@"module:%f", module);

if (module == 0){

    NSLog(@"MODULEEEEE");
}
```

"self.count_bar" is a double that I increment in a timer but when it arrive at "0.3", it doesn't print "MODULEEEE", I don't understand... why?

Comment: Do you set self.count_bar directly to 0.3 or increase it by 0.1 ?

Comment: I increase it every 0.01 (timer) of 0.01 (value)

Answer (score 0):

Comparing floating-point types for equality almost always burns you (and can be dangerous even for other comparisons, depending on context). This is because of how computers store floating point numbers and perform comparisons.

You can switch the comparison to check if module > 0, then the condition will be false until self.count_bar reaches 0.3 and then will be true afterwards. If that's not what you want, then you can calculate the absolute value of the difference between module and 0, and choose a threshold value (0.01, 0.001, 0.0001, etc., depends on what you're doing) to say "close enough." When that absolute value of the difference is less than your threshold, then display your message.

Comment: I understand... so finally I found a solution to use integer, thanks for the replay